# What's the difference between "ConnectionSuccess" and ”ConnectionCreated" in Socket?

Tags: c++, sockets, ns-3

I saw the source code of the implementation of Socket class in NS-3 and I saw there are two member functions:

```cpp
  /**
   * \brief Notify through the callback (if set) that the connection has been
   *        established.
   */
  void NotifyConnectionSucceeded (void);
```

and

```cpp
  /**
   * \brief Notify through the callback (if set) that a new connection has been
   *        created.
   * \param socket The socket receiving the new connection.
   * \param from The address of the node initiating the connection.
   */
  void NotifyNewConnectionCreated (Ptr<Socket> socket, const Address &from);
```

So what's the main difference between these two functions? and is there any difference between "ConnectionSucceed" and "ConnectionCreated"?

Comment: From a quick look at the documentation, I think that `NotifyConnectionSucceeded` is for outbound connections and `NotifyNewConnectionCreated` is for inbound connections.  But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From the [ns-3 TCP model documentation](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/models/html/tcp.html):

> *NotifyConnectionSucceeded: SetConnectCallback*, 1st argument
>
> Called in the SYN_SENT state, before moving to ESTABLISHED. In other words, we have sent the SYN, and we received the SYN-ACK: the socket prepares the sequence numbers, sends the ACK for the SYN-ACK, tries to send out more data (in another segment) and then invokes this callback. After this callback, it invokes the NotifySend callback.

> *NotifyNewConnectionCreated: SetAcceptCallback*, 2nd argument
>
> Invoked when from SYN_RCVD the socket passes to ESTABLISHED, and after setting up the congestion control, the sequence numbers, and processing the incoming ACK. If there is some space in the buffer, NotifySend is called shortly after this callback. The Socket pointer, passed with this callback, is the newly created socket, after a Fork().

So, what @Paul Sanders says is essentially correct: `NotifyConnectionSucceeded` is called when the TcpSocket that initiated the connection (ie. sent SYN) receives SYN+ACK. On the other hand, `NotifyNewConnectionCreated` is called when a TcpSocket that sent SYN+ACK receives the ACK that completes the 3-way handshake. Look at [`tcp-socket-base.cc`](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/tcp-socket-base_8cc_source.html) to see exactly how these methods are used.

The above is particular to TCP, and as you rightly point out, these methods belong to Socket. Other types of Sockets will use these methods differently. For example, [UdpSockets](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/models/html/udp.html) use `NotifyConnectionSucceeded`, but do not support `NotifyNewConnectionCreated`.